# Batch renaming files before certain character

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a bunch of Pdf files with names like so:

```
Malcolm Gaskill - History.pdf 
Manfred B. Steger - Globalization; A Very Short Introduction.pdf
```

I want to rename them to get rid of everything before the first hyphen so they end up like:

```
History.pdf 
Globalization; A Very Short Introduction.pdf
```

How do I go about doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*-*.pdf" '
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=*" %%d IN ("%%c") DO (
   ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%~a" "%%~d"
  )
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Not particularly easy for a beginner, since the filenames may contain <kbd>;</kbd> which is a separator like <kbd>Space</kbd>

First, perform a `dir /b` to get all of the required filenames which are applied to `%%a` using `for /f` with no delimiters.

Next, tokenise using `-` into `%%b` and `%%c`, then remove leading separators from `%%c` using `tokens=*` applying required filename to `%%d`.

Then mix-and-match to build the required rename command.

Comment: I'd set `eol` to `:` or `|` which are invalid characters for file names; this would allow file names to contain/begin with semicolons `;`...